# Select particular words in a string

Tags: bash

string (contents1) contains the following

> 755572 ZR66_op/Res7.fcp 755676 ZR66_op/Res-Edited-MP3-Files 755677 ZR66_op/Res-Files 756876 ZR66_op/Res-Edited-WAV-Files 758228 ZR67_op/Res5.fcp 758224 ZR66_op/Res-Original-Audio-Files 758225 ZR67_op/Res-Edited-Files

I want to collect only the following into string (contents2)

> 755572 ZR66_op/Res7.fcp 755676 ZR66_op/Res-Edited-MP3-Files 755677 ZR66_op/Res-Files 756876 ZR66_op/Res-Edited-WAV-Files 758224 ZR66_op/Res-Original-Audio-Files

the `ZR66_op` will be the search element

Can any one help me in this

Comment: In your output, "755676" does not contain "ZR66_op". Is this a mistake in your output, or is it grouped with the previous string? (I'm assuming that your strings are whitespace delimited).

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern matching:

```
#! /bin/bash
search=ZR66_op

contents1=755572\ ZR66_op/Res7.fcp\ \
755676\ ZR66_op/Res-Edited-MP3-Files\ \
755677\ ZR66_op/Res-Files\ \
756876\ ZR66_op/Res-Edited-WAV-Files\ \
758228\ ZR67_op/Res5.fcp\ \
758224\ ZR66_op/Res-Original-Audio-Files\ \
758225\ ZR67_op/Res-Edited-Files

ar=($contents1)

for (( i=0; i/2<=${#ar}; i+=2 )) ; do
    if [[ ${ar[i+1]} == "$search"* ]] ; then
        contents2+="${ar[i]} ${ar[i+1]} "
    fi
done

contents2=${contents2% } # Remove the extra space
echo "$contents2"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with a whitespace delimited string, and you are pulling tokens off the string in fixed sized sets (pairs, triples, etc.), you can use 'read' to load the tokens into variables:

```
#! /bin/bash
contents1='755572 ZR66_op/Res7.fcp 755676 ZR66_op/Res-Edited-MP3-Files 755677 ZR66_op/Res-Files 756876 ZR66_op/Res-Edited-WAV-Files 758228 ZR67_op/Res5.fcp 758224 ZR66_op/Res-Original-Audio-Files 758225 ZR67_op/Res-Edited-Files'

search=ZR66_op

contents2=""
while read number filename
do
    if [[ $filename == "$search"* ]]
    then
        contents2="$contents2 $number $filename "
    fi
done <<< $contents1

echo $contents2
```

Comment: That will NOT maintain the `contents2` variable: because you're **piping** input into a while-loop, the loop will be run in a **subshell**. Any variable updates in the subshell will be lost when the subshell exits. You need `while read ...; done <<< "$contents1"`

Comment: Ah, nuts. I used the pipe because I thought that it was clearer... never considered that it would spawn a subshell. Editing accordingly.